# How should you pronounce MongoDB?

Tags: pronunciation, ambiguity

**Backstory** *(skip this if you want)*: I've been programming in JavaScript for
a while, and for the longest time I've been using a database system called
"MongoDB". I come from Australia and I believe I have been preconditioned by my
culture (along with most of my friends) to pronounce it the first way in the list below. Hopefully you can understand my confusion.

**The real question:** I have heard it said these ways (in order of frequency):

1. Mong-oh-dee-bee
2. Mon-go-dee-bee
3. Both of the above, but with 'dee-bee' replaced by 'deb'

**Which is correct?**

Comment: I can't tell the difference between 1 and 2

Comment: @toryan The first sounds a little like *mango*; the second, like *men go*.

Comment: Since *MongoDB* is a made-up word, ask the developer. I also found this on the web: [How to Pronounce Mongo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJAGmBRXdPM).

Comment: Dwight Merriman pronounces it Mong-go-Dee-Bee https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GfDpzaLhYlU. I’d take that to be pretty authoritative.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for finding that - I didn't see it before. Add that as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @toryan:  It's also similar to (although not exactly the same as) the difference between *singer* and *ginger* — in *singer*, the G is pronounced in the first syllable; in *ginger*, the (second) G is pronounced in the second syllable.   (Compare to *finger*, where the G is pronounced in *both* syllables.)

Comment: Scott - in British English ginger has both G's pronounced the same way - like a J.

Comment: @RoryAlsop:  It's the same in AmE.  So what?  My point is that "_inger" is pronounced three different ways in three different words, and that that phenomenon is similar to (although not exactly the same as) the difference between the first two pronunciations of "Mongo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mongo** rhymes with *Bongo*

DB is always *dee-bee* in computing

Seems fairly straightforward to me.